# HP 1910-48G troubleshooting

Tags: networking, switch

I have acquired a old HP 1910-48G gigabit switch. I have been able to reset it to defaults and assign a IP to it. Using the web portal I have configured the rest. I use google wifi and then go into the switches. When I go straight from the google wifi to the HP switch non of my devices are able to talk to each other. BUT when I go from the google wifi to a simple switch then to the HP switch my desktop that is plugged into the HP switch is able to work. Any assistance, do i have to set up a trunk port I also do not have any vlans.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBbEU.png

Comment: By default everything should be in vlan1 with no tagging if you don't want to use vlans. If you have changed the default or are tagging ports it is probably confusing the other hardware.

Comment: Do the link LEDs light up? Possibly neither Google Wifi nor 1910 supports Auto MDI-X and the two MDI-X ports simply won't link (without a crossover cable/adapter).